# Distinguishing between kinds of roku devices based on user agent string?

Tags: user-agent, roku

Are there any distinguishing characteristics of user-agent strings for different kinds of Roku devices? For example, given a user agent string like `Roku/DVP-5.0 (025.00E08043A)` is there a way to tell whether the device is Roku Premiere or Roku Ultra?

From online databases like https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_name/roku-digital-video-player/1, I wasn't able to tell whether Roku Premiere always has a different user agent string from Roku Ultra. [Posts](https://community.roku.com/t5/Roku-Developer-Program/User-Agent-string/td-p/444386) from the Roku Developer community don't clarify either.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't.
Unless you explicitly override the user-agent header `r.addheader("User-Agent","myvalue")` on your HTTP requests.
The default UA just tells you the build version and OS version.

You can override the UA header and get the model name from [here](https://developer.roku.com/en-gb/docs/references/brightscript/interfaces/ifdeviceinfo.md#getmodeldisplayname-as-string).